# WASP PowerShell 32 bits

Tags: powershell, x86, 64-bit, wasp

I am using WASP successfully with PowerShell 64 bits, but I need to use PowerShell 32 bits cause of  OCR MODI.Document.

But my PowerShell x86 is not able to load my WASP module : 
[See when I am trying to reach WASP module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBvtv.png)
How is it possible? I've run both with administrator account ...

I've never seen that--I gave rights to everyone, but I can't reach my folder [Right for folder WASP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBwxA.png)

Answer (score 1):

For module to be accessible from both x86 and x64 PS, it should be in:

```
$Home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules (%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules)

$Env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules (%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules)
```

You shouldn't install modules in

```
$PSHome\Modules (%Windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules)
```

because

> This location is reserved for modules that ship with Windows. Do not
>   install modules to this location.

See this document: [Installing a PowerShell Module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350.aspx).

Here is screenshot of [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), showing that x86 PS doesn't look into the x64 module directory when trying to import module:

[image: ProcMon]